# Kubernetes Mapping

Tags: kubernetes, networking

Is there a way to map external services to internal pods?
E.g. if the pod calls `www.google.com` it should call an internal pod `fake-google`
I saw some ways to do it with `/etc/hosts` [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/), but I don't have an ip here to hardcode, only the svc name.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Marcelo Adamatti welcome to SO. Every `Service` in kubernetes is also assigned a fixed IP over its lifespan, so yes, you do have an IP to use in that `/etc/hosts` trick -- they're visible via `kubectl get -o wide svc $the_fake_google_service_name`. Good luck

Comment: `/etc/hosts` is **not** the right place for what you are asking **if you do not want to use IP addresses**. IF you want to map one hostname to another hostname, it's a work of `CNAME` . This has been requested by many people in past, check out some work around discussed https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39792

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel, if I got it right hardcode ip is not a good approach as if I deploy a new instance the IP will change (and I will need to change in all usages).